# Remote desktop printing not working

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, printing

I am using remote desktop to connect to an external machine. The end goal I am trying to achive is to log in to the external machine and send printing jobs to a printer connected to my local machine. The Printer option in RD settings
[is activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfHxV.png).

Also I made sure that exactly the same printer driver is installed on both machines. Both machines are Windows 7 Pro-s. However, my local printer did not show up in external's computer printer list.

Finally my coworker installed the same driver and I logged into his computer using RD.  This way I managed to send a printing job from his machine to my local printer.

I am thinking the problem might be with external's machine services. I checked that the "Print Spooler" service is running ands starts automatically. Maybe some neccessary services are not running. However, I have not found any information from the Internet which mentions the neccessary services for printing.

Comment: This is a site for professional system administrators.  I do not think that you are a system administrator.

Comment: Before asking I searched and found several questions about remote printing, like this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/49399/remote-desktop-printing-with-color
And yes, I am not a professional sysadmin, but I would appreciate good advice.

Comment: The only correct advice is that you need to speak to the admin that looks after the RDP server.  Your problem is probably that you don't have the exact same matching drivers installed on the client and server (although it could be something else).  There's event log entries that will show what the issue is.  This question might be suitable for SuperUser.